# Excel error #REF formula after removing columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a basic excel question. I have 3 columns A,B and C.

Column C is sum of A and B or any other formula using A and B. I want to remove A and B column now. Column C change into `#REF`.

```
----------
A | B | C
1 | 5 | =A1+B1
----------
```

One solution is to create column D, Copy column C and paste as value in column D then delete A,B and C and keep Column D.

Is there any better solution like adding something in the formula?

Many Thanks

Comment: Copy paste column C as values so hard coded then remove the preceeding columns.

Comment: I mentioned this solution but I am looking for an efficient one.

Comment: You mentioned a less efficient variation on this solution. Why create another column and transfer? Do in place. And what do you think is more efficient than copy paste as values in place? You can't have a reference to a column then delete that column and not get #Ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to use indirect references as follows

```
=INDIRECT("A" & ROW()) + INDIRECT("B" & ROW())
```

Then Excel can never mess with your formulae.

(Note that this produces an error while columns A and B are temporarily absent. However, once you put them back everything returns to normal.)

Comment: Brilliant, this is the answer I was looking for. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, out of one simple reason:
**Your formula is `referencing` a specific cell**

If you wish to remove data in Column A or B while maintaining the result, then simply:

1. Click on the topmost cell in Column C

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>▼</kbd> to select all the data (til first empty row)
3. Copy to clipboard via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or alternatively <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select Paste as Values

   [image]

---

Other option is to create an illusion of changing data:

1. Begin with your data in Column C instead of A, like so and select the columns with data:
   [image]
2. Rightclick with mouse on the selected columns and select Hide
   (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> <sup>*non-numpad*</sup>)

   [image]
3. Thus creating the illusion you have a functioning referencing formula with two columns being empty:

   [image]

---

*Though truth be told, whatever you're trying to do, it seems like a rather unnecessary idea.

Why not just leave data as it is?*